# Why does python execute if statment before button is clicked in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#Mbox
from tkinter import *

list2= ['charlie','sam','lolo']

def Turn():
   list2=['charlie']     


def Box():
    global list2
    popup = Tk()
    label = Label(popup,text='jack').pack()
    button = Button(popup,text='lew',command=lambda: Turn()).pack()

    if len(list2) == 1:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')

    popup.mainloop()

Box()
```

When Ran the output is no, why is this? and is there any way of getting around it besides from creating an extra function. the code is an example of the problem I'm trying to solve not the actual code, so try not to change the code so that the if statement lies in the function Turn()

Comment: The `if` statement is inside `Box`, which is run as soon as your program is executed. The stuff that happens when your button is pressed is in the `Turn` function. What is your confusion?

Comment: The execution of Box() doesn't stop to wait for you to click the button. I think you have to reorganize your code.

Comment: it isn't necessarily about the confusion but I need to find a way of clicking the button first then allow the if statement at the bottom to be then executed.

Comment: Well this is not the way to do what you want.  Think a little, if the program stops to wait for the click, you wont see the button at all, cause your mainloop() function will never run. This is an event driven app, so you need to do something on the interface to execute that if statement and get what you want.

Comment: What is the problem you're actually trying to solve.  In general, you would try to do things like this with objects and not functions.  Think of a Box object that gets packed with buttons.  in a separate place you would run the tkinter mainloop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the if statement in its own function and just add it to your lambda call.

Take a look at the below example and let me know if you have any questions.

```
from tkinter import *

list2 = ['charlie', 'sam', 'lolo']

def Turn():
    global list2
    list2 = ['charlie']

def run_if_statment():
    global list2
    if len(list2) == 1:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')   

def Box():
    global list2
    popup = Tk()
    Label(popup, text='jack').pack()
    Button(popup, text='lew', command=lambda:(Turn(), run_if_statment())).pack()
    popup.mainloop()

Box()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You are checking the length of the list in Box function which will start when the program starts. But to check, you must put if else in the Turn function and when the button is clicked, it will execute the turn command checking if the condition is true

```
def Turn():
    list2=['charlie']     

    if len(list2) == 1:
       print('yes')
    else:
       print('no')
```

Comment: This is always going to print 'yes'

Comment: @lpozo well based on the code the OP provided and what they said they are trying to do then yes the answer will always be yes no mater how you decide to set it up. It is more likely that the OP just used `turn` as an example but there may be more complex code on their program. Maybe turn toggles something instead of just changing the list to 1 length.